# Как правильно определить путь к медиа файлам?

Tags: android

Пытаюсь проиграть файл mp3, который храниться не на съемной карте памяти а во внутренней памяти телефона, но проиграть его не удается:

```
    public void onPlayMusic(View view){
        mediaPlayerMusic = new MediaPlayer();
        try {
            mediaPlayerMusic
.setDataSource("content://media/external/audio/media/John Frusciante - God");
            mediaPlayerMusic.prepare();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        mediaPlayerMusic.setOnCompletionListener(this);
        musicAFlistener = new AFlistener(mediaPlayerMusic, "MUSIC");
        int requestResult = audioManager.requestAudioFocus(musicAFlistener,
 AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN);
        Log.d(TAG, "music requested audiofocus -> " + requestResult);
        mediaPlayerMusic.start();
    }

        @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer){
                if (mediaPlayer == mediaPlayerMusic){
                    audioManager.abandonAudioFocus(musicAFlistener);
                    Log.d(TAG, "music abandoned audiofocus");
                }
            }
```

p.s. musicAFlistener реализует интерфейс OnAudioFocusChangeListener.

После вызова метода onPlayMusic(View view) сразу срабатывает onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer), как будто бы проблема в пути к файлу, который я находил следующим образом:

```
ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();
        storeUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
        Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(storeUri, null, null, null, null);
        if (cursor != null & cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            int cursorTitle = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE);
            do {
                String title = cursor.getString(cursorTitle);
                String pathToResource = storeUri + "/" + title;
                Log.i(TAG, "TITLE = " + title);
                Log.i(TAG, "PATH = " + pathToResource); // выбираю любой интересующий!
            }while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Все, разобрался: для ресурса, который в EXTERNAL_CONTENT нужен 
    setDataSource с другими параметрами:

```
    final Uri DATA_URI = ContentUris
            .withAppendedId(
                    android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                    URI_DATA);
```

после нахождения курсора:

```
int idColumn = cursor
        .getColumnIndex(android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID);
long thisId = cursor.getLong(idColumn); // это наш URI_DATA
setDataSource с другими параметрами:
```

В onPlayMusic вызываем:

```
mediaPlayerMusic.setDataSource(this, DATA_URI);
```